# How do I avoid duplicate rows using FREETEXT?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  cat.CategoryId,cat.CategoryName,cat.CategoryImageURL,cat.CategoryImageData,
  ap.AppName,ap.AppImageData,ap.AppDetails,ap.AppId
FROM Category cat,App ap
WHERE FREETEXT (cat.CategoryName, 'App')
```

[image]
How do I avoid duplicate rows in these results?

Comment: They don't look like duplicate rows to me - AppName is different, for example. If you want to eliminate duplicates you need to tell us which AppName you want, which AppImageData, etc. Also why are you using a cross join? Is that supposed to be an inner join on some kind of application identifier perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fulltext query will only return a row 1 time.  However, it looks like you are doing a Cartesian join between Category and App.  You need some type of join to be defined.  For example:

```
SELECT cat.CategoryId,cat.CategoryName,cat.CategoryImageURL,cat.CategoryImageData,ap.AppName,ap.AppImageData,ap.AppDetails,ap.AppId
  FROM Category cat JOIN App ap
       ON cat.CategoryID = ap.CategoryID    
  WHERE FREETEXT (cat.CategoryName, 'App')
```

(Obviously I do not know the actual join criteria.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using a CROSS JOIN for some reason:

```
FROM Category cat,App ap
```

I assume this should have been an inner join, but I have absolutely no idea how you tie a category to an app. I also don't understand why you bother aliasing `App` as `ap`...

```
FROM dbo.Category AS cat
INNER JOIN dbo.App
ON cat.<magic> = App.AppId
```